# Intercept all Node's require calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I'm trying to figure out how to intercept all Node's `require` calls, so that I can log them.

There are a few questions about this already but the suggested methods there fail at intercepting *all* require calls for me, i.e. I want to *deeply* intercept require calls, also those made inside my required modules, and their required modules and so on.

So far I've tried the following 3 methods:

```js
const _req = require;
global.require = function () {
  console.log ( 'require', arguments );
  return _req.apply ( this, arguments );
};
```

```js
const Module = require ( 'module' );
const _load = Module._load;
Module._load = function () {
  console.log ( 'require', arguments );
  return _load.apply ( this, arguments );
};
```

```js
const Module = require ( 'module' );
const _wrap = Module.wrap;
Module.wrap = function(script) {
  const prepend = `console.log ( module.id );`;
  script = prepend + script;
  return _wrap(script);
};
```

But none of them worked for me.

I'm under Node.js v12 running inside Electron v5.

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve something like this (`Intercept all require calls`) would would most likely need to wrap the `Module.prototype.require`.

```
Module.prototype.require = wrapWithYOURInterceptor(params);
```

This is done in various "intercept" `require` libs as you can see:

1. [intercept-require](https://github.com/bttmly/intercept-require): https://github.com/bttmly/intercept-require/blob/master/lib/index.js
2. [require-hook](https://bitbucket.org/ralphv/require-hook/src/master/): https://bitbucket.org/ralphv/require-hook/src/master/lib/requireHook.js

You can also just use those libs instead of embarking on a new lib etc.

Comment: I've tried `intercept-require` but it isn't able to intercept all require calls for me. Given that `require-hook` works in a similar manner I suppose it would also not work for me.